# Bind Textfield Label to store value

Tags: extjs

I am using `ExtJs6.2` Modern toolkit.I have a situation where all my display labels are stored in `DB` and I need to use those to display on my `form`.

> example

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    readOnly: true,
    scrollable: false,
    label: ** showFromStore ** ,
    labelAlign: 'top',
    name: 'someName',
    bind: '{SomeValue}'
},
```

What would be the best way to manage this display on the `forms`?

Comment: A store is supposed to be a collection of records. Where are you getting the value from?

Answer (score 2):

For binding all config of [`textfield`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html) or any other EXTJS `component` you can use [`bind`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html#cfg-bind) config.

> Example

```
Ext.create({
     xtype: 'textfield',
     bind: {
         label: '{user.label}',
         name: '{user.name}',
         value: '{user.value}',
     }
})
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f5n)**, I have created a demo using `viewmodel`, `formpanel` and `textfield`. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        //defining view model
        Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

            alias: 'viewmodel.myvm',

            data: {
                users: null
            },

            stores: {
                formstore: {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'namelabel', 'phonelabel', 'emaillabel'],
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        url: 'data.json',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: ''
                        }
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        load: function (store, data, success) {
                            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myform')[0].getViewModel().set('users', data[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //creating form
        Ext.create({

            xtype: 'formpanel',

            itemId: 'myform',

            title: 'Form example',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            fullscreen: true,

            viewModel: {
                type: 'myvm'
            },

            defaults: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                readOnly: true
            },

            items: [{
                bind: {
                    label: '{users.namelabel}',
                    value: '{users.name}'
                }
            }, {
                bind: {
                    label: '{users.emaillabel}',
                    value: '{users.email}'
                }
            }, {
                bind: {
                    label: '{users.phonelabel}',
                    value: '{users.phone}'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

**JSON CODE**

```
[{
    "name": "Lisa Doshi",
    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
    "phone": "555-111-1224",
    "namelabel": "Full Name",
    "emaillabel": "Email Address",
    "phonelabel": "Phone Number"
}]
```

Comment: Unlike this example, the data that I want to bind to the textbox label is a set of records in another store- an array. How can I bind a single item? I tried doing  label: '{labelstore.data[0].phonelabel}' but this does not work.

Comment: can you provide the your efforts? so I can try to check

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to create a Fiddle to demonstrate this,but I will try to provide all details here

```
data returned from service is 
 [{"ID":"P1","Label":"Procedure"},{"ID":"P2","Label":"Process"},, 
 {"ID":"P3","Label":"Problem"}]
```

I am loading this data in a store

```
    Ext.define('My.store.myLabels',
    {
        alias: 'store.Lang',
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        config:
        {
            fields: ['ID', 'Label'],
            pageSize: 10000,
            proxy:
            {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: myserviceURL
        }
    }
});
```

Now how do I bind a single value from the store here

```
xtype: 'textfield',
readOnly: true,
scrollable: false,
labelAlign: 'top',
name: 'Process',
itemId: 'P1',
bind:{
       value: '{somevalue}',
       label:  * how to bind the value of P1 here *,
}
```

I tried a formula: but with that I would have to write a formula for each UI element.
So my question is:

1. How to access a single item from the store to bind it here like:

   store.data.items["0"].ID.P1
2. Or how to access the component
   ID/itemId that triggered the view model formula  so that I can do

   ```
   displayLabel: {
     get: function (get) {
           var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('myLabels');
            //search the store based on item id of the component that 
             //triggered the formula
             if (index > -1) {
               return store.getAt(index).data.Label;
              }

        }
   ```

   }

Comment: Instead of here you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49616673/edit)  your question and paste the there